# Motivation for definition of tangent space to a point on an affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $d_x: k[X] \to \Phi_x^*$ where $k[X]$ is the coordinate ring of an affine variety $X$ and $\Phi_x^*$ is the dual of the tangent space of $x \in X$.

Shafarevich in "Basic Algebraic Geometry 1" writes that since $d_x \alpha = 0$ for all $\alpha \in k$ we look instead at the map $d_x : \frak{m}_x \to \Phi_x^*$ where $\frak{m}_x$ $:= \{ f \in k[X] \vert f(x) = 0 \}$.

Why does $f$ not vanishing at $x$ imply that $d_x f= 0$ ?

Comment: it doesn't. ${}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a polynomial that doesn't vanish at zero, say $3x^5 + 4x^2 - 7$.  Then this polynomial is the sum of a polynomial that *does* vanish at zero, namely $3x^5 + 4x^2$, and a constant polynomial, namely $7$.  The latter has vanishing differential, so it's enough to consider the differentials of polynomials which *do* vanish at zero.